# Show textbox when button is click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to hide and show the password of the user but I'm having a hard time. Here is my markup:

```
<td>Username: <td>
<td><input type="text" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $row['Username'];?>"readonly><td>
<td><input type="button" class="btn btn-primary show" value="Show Password">
<input type="button" class="btn btn-primary hide" value="Hide Password" style="display:none;"><td>
</tr>
<tr  class="password" style="display:none;">
<td>Password: <td>
<td><input type="text" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $row['Password']; ?>" readonly><td>
</tr>
```

And my jQuery

```
$(".show").click(function(){
$('.hide').show();
$('.show').hide();});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your HTML is invalid, you need to wrap a **table** tag around a **tr** tag or the **tr** and everything in it will return **undefined** in Javascript:

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td>Username:
        <td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $row['Username'];?>" readonly>
                <td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary show" value="Show Password">
                        <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary hide" value="Hide Password" style="display:none;">
                        <td>
</tr>
<tr class="password" style="display:none;">
    <td>Password:
        <td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $row['Password'];?>" readonly>
                <td>
</tr>
                </table>
```

and to complete your JQuery, you could use this:

```
$(".show").click(function () {
    $('.hide').show();
    $(this).hide();
    $('.password').eq(0).show();
});

$('.hide').click(function () {
    $('.show').show();
    $(this).hide();
    $('.password').eq(0).hide();
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/L3TtU/2/)

Answer (score 1):

You need a [unique] identifier for your password textbox and for your jQuery selector to point to it.

Example:

```
<td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="pwd" value="<?php echo $row['Password']; ?>" readonly><td>
```

And your jQuery selector should therefore look for am element with `id="pwd"`:

```
$(".show").click(function(){
    $('#pwd').show();
});

$(".hide").click(function(){
    $('#pwd').hide();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You also can use [.toggle()](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) method like

```
$(".show").click(function () {
    $('.hide').toggle();
    $(this).toggle();
    $('.password').eq(0).toggle();
});

$('.hide').click(function () {
    $('.show').toggle();
    $(this).toggle();
    $('.password').eq(0).toggle();
});
```

### [Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pmqAc/)

Also do some little changes to HTML as suggested by @Man of Snow..